# Firebase: How do I get the ID Token for a signed-in user on the client side if I am using server-side session cookies?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I am using Firebase Cloud Functions with Express and Firebase Hosting to serve my multi-page site. I have successfully implemented server-side cookies as explained [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-cookies) and as implemented below:

```
function verifyLogin(request, response, next) {
    const sessionCookie = request.cookies.__session || '';
    firebase.auth().verifySessionCookie(sessionCookie, true /** checkRevoked */ )
        .then((decodedClaims) => {
            //serve content for user
            return next();
        }).catch(error => {
            // Session cookie is unavailable or invalid. Force user to log in.
            console.log(error);
            response.redirect('/login');
            return;
        });
}

app.get('/', verifyLogin, (request, response) => {
    var page_title = "Home";
    response.render('index', {
        page_title,
    });
});
```

I am using the Firebase Web SDK (JavaScript) to access the Firebase Cloud Firestore. In order to do this, I need to get the idToken on the client side for the currently-logged-in user, like so:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(firebaseUser => {
    if (firebaseUser) {
        firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdTokenResult()
            .then((idTokenResult) => {
                 // Access the Firebase Cloud Firestore here
            });
    }
});
```

This seems redundant to me, since I already know which user is signed in via my server cookie, but how else can I get the idToken without another call to Firebase Auth?

Is there a way to extrapolate it from my session cookie somehow and pass it to my client from my cloud function as a variable?

Or is there another way to look at this philosophically that I am overlooking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the same way you can listen to user sign-in state changes using `onAuthStateChanged()`, you can also listen to user ID token changes using [onIdTokenChanged()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#onidtokenchanged).  You will only need to use a new token when the observer you attach shows that a new one appears (for example, when it's refreshed every hour by the SDK).

Comment: Does this still require accessing the Authentication app? I was hoping to avoid another roundtrip to the server and figured since I already had an authenticated user on the server side I could just pass that token to the client. My app doesn't require any listeners because I basically just load the data needed at page load time, so there's no need to monitor for changes to a user's authentication status until the page changes, which, again, is all handled on the server side.

Comment: There's no round trip.  It tells you when there's an update, and you start using the new ID token in your calls to the backend. There's nothing else to do.

Comment: Thanks. That clears it up. Still learning, so I appreciate the help.

Comment: @BenS did you get this to work? I'm in a similar situation, but can't figure out how to get the client to recognize a logged-in user